# restful service parameters in headers or body

Tags: rest

I am developing a restful web service based on a database query and the tool that i am using tends to generate the parameters as a part of the HTTP Header ?
I always thought the parameters for POST to the restful service should always be passed in HTTP Body ?

Any ideas what should be the best practice or the usual practice ?

Comment: What parameters? What kind of request, `GET`, `POST`, ...?

Comment: I thought anything sensitive would get passed in the header but everything else is generally passed in the URI or in the body as you mentioned. GET is via the URI and POST / PUT pass via the body.

Comment: It really depends on the *type* of parameters.

Comment: @DrSchizo, to add to what you said, avoiding sensitive data in the URI is important to avoid users inadvertently sharing it through the URI, but HTTPS encrypts the request path, not just the body, just as an FYI for anyone who might be confused on the matter.

Comment: Michael do you mean to say the URI and Body are both encrypted if we use HTTPS ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The domain is not encrypted (it will be sent unencrypted during DNS resolution), but the entire content of the HTTP request is sent over an encrypted channel (that includes both the URI and body) when using an HTTPS connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For POST requests, you can do either, but generally you'll use the body of the request for *content* that you are appending, mutating, deleting, etc. or for any data that is simply too large to put in the URI while one generally uses URI parameters for information that identifies the resource that is being accessed or modified (such as the element's ID) or restrictions or other search criteria (e.g. page, limit, etc.).

The primary tradeoffs off the top of my head  are linkability (do you need a special POST extension, for example, just for developers to test a particular handler on your server?), URI size limits, and also whether the user would need to perform a click in order to cause the request to be sent (though using POST body is not a substitute for requiring a valid XSRF token/signature on the request).

Did I miss any other tradeoffs?